# can not add user input to the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Here is the code and the cosole.log is showing the correct value of the city. value of the city is passing from another js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import  { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Content=(city)=>{

const [cities, setItems] = useState([]);
console.log(city);


useEffect((city) => {
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},LK&mode=json ,appid=5c4420d5c8a61c16e5ee37e4ca265763`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      setItems(cities => cities.concat(result));
    },
  )
  },[]);

  console.log(cities);

 return (
  
  
  <h2>hello</h2>
  );
}


export default Content;
```

I think the problem is with the ${city} but I tried everything that I know to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be in the URL, where you have a typo for the query params (you have a comma between `mode` and `appid` and it should be a &).

It should be

```
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},LK&mode=json&appid=5c4420d5c8a61c16e5ee37e4ca265763`)
```

By the way, `mode=json` is not necessary, since JSON is the default response mode.

Comment: @nermoo have you tried to `console.log(res)` inside the first `.then(...)` to see if the fetch is being done correctly?

Comment: yes sir. then i tried sending the whole API instead just of the 'city'. it did update the API and replace the 'city' with the user input. but now I'm having a bigger problem of not fetching data. guess I'll have to study more about the state management. Thanks for the help ✌